# Readonly WaitHandle C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, waithandle

I am exposing a `WaitHandle` on an interface for an object that's responsible for creating a resource internally, but it may take a long time.  The contract looks like this:

```
public interface IHaveExpensiveResources {
    WaitHandle FinishedInitialization { get; }
}
```

The `WaitHandle` starts unset, but then I set it once the initialization completes (in the background, after the constructor returns).  The thing I don't like about this is that consumers of this contract can set the `WaitHandle` themselves, when they have no business being able to do this.  It reminds me of the difference between a get-only [`IList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx) property and a [`IReadOnlyList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx).

Is there anything in C# like a `WaitOnlyWaitHandle` which only exposes the `WaitOne()` overloaded methods?

So that I'm not a victim of the XY problem, is there a more canonical way of asynchronously constructing objects which have long construction times?

Comment: Do you have to pass back a `WaitHandle` or could you make your own wrapper class that only exposes the functions you want, similar to what [ReadOnlyCollection](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/readonlycollection.cs) does?

Comment: +1 to own wrapper class. BTW, have you considered an option of returning `Task` instead of `WaitHandle`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Yeah, I could create a wrapper class which really contains a `WaitHandle`, and create my own contract.

Comment: @alex.b I have, but could I do that with a constructor or do I need a factory method?  I suppose I could return a Task which wraps the `WaitHandle.WaitOne()` method call.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I'll make a wrapper class like Scott Chamberlain suggested and perhaps I will create a factory so I have the features that the TPL gives you if people want to use that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have to pass back a `WaitHandle` or could you make your own wrapper class that only exposes the functions you want, similar to what ReadOnlyCollection does?

One option is to wrap the WaitHandle up in to a task (Code example taken from [the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#WHToTap))

```
public static Task WaitOneAsync(this WaitHandle waitHandle)
{
    if (waitHandle == null) 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("waitHandle");

    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
    var rwh = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(waitHandle, 
        delegate { tcs.TrySetResult(true); }, null, -1, true);
    var t = tcs.Task;
    t.ContinueWith( (antecedent) => rwh.Unregister(null));
    return t;
}
```

Then you just call `.WaitOneAsync()` on whatever `FinishedInitialization` would have been returning and return that `Task` instead.

Comment: As always, you're answer is very enlightening.  Thanks very much

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, this is the interface and implementation that I created for exposing on the `WaitOne()` overloaded methods on `WaitHandle`

```
public interface IWaitOnlyWaitHandle
{
    bool WaitOne();
    bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout);
    bool WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout);
    bool WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext);
    bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout, bool exitContext);
}

public sealed class WaitOnlyWaitHandle : IWaitOnlyWaitHandle
{
    # UPDATE: this object does not own the passed in WaitHandle
    private readonly WaitHandle _waitHandle;
    public WaitOnlyWaitHandle(WaitHandle waitHandle)
    {
        _waitHandle = waitHandle;
    }

    public bool WaitOne() => _waitHandle.WaitOne();
    public bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout) => _waitHandle.WaitOne(timeout);
    public bool WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout) => _waitHandle.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout);
    public bool WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) => _waitHandle.WaitOne(millisecondsTimeout, exitContext);
    public bool WaitOne(TimeSpan timeout, bool exitContext) => _waitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, exitContext);
}
```

UPDATE: as per @stevenbone's comment, this implementation does not own the lifecycle for the `WaitHandle` that is passed in to the constructor.  Read his comments for more info.

Comment: Adding IDisposable to the IWaitOnlyWaitHandle interface does not get you what you desire. I'd eliminate IDisposable and the Dispose() method from interface and wrapper, inherit a class from WaitHandle and add a method "public IWaitOnlyWaitHandle AsWaitOnly()" to it that returns your wrapper - similar to List<T>.AsReadOnly() does. Locally, you can act on it as a WaitHandle (to set and dispose), and you can provide the truly wait-only wrapper to clients. Then you don't need to worry about who manages the disposal of the waithandle and prevent misuse.

Comment: @stevenbone Perhaps one could create the wait handle in the constructor to prevent the same issues, with fewer modifications

Comment: If that were the case, how would one Set or Dispose it?

Comment: @stevenbone I think you're right about calling `Set` on it, but disposing it would happen in the same way as in the sample.  Your answer I think is correct (using `AsWaitOnly()`), though.  I'll update the answer.